# Is there a vanilla JS equivalent of jQuery .has()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What would be the vanilla JS equivalent of :has in this jQuery selector?

```
$('.main-container').children('.analytics:has(a)').not('#promo')
```

Within `.main-container`, I'm trying to select all `.analytics` elements without an id of "promo" that contain `<a>` tags.

**What I've tried:**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.main-container .analytics:not(#promo)')
```

This will give me close to what I want, but I still have to filter out those `.analytics` parents that do **NOT** have `<a>` tags.

What would be the best way to approach this using vanilla JS?

Comment: it's not an exact match but you could try the contains method

Comment: How about looping throught the results of the `querySelectorAll` and only apply the rules where `this.getElementsByTagName('a').length > 0`?

Comment: Is it not an easier way to select by using classes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Query the document for using your desired selector, in this case: `.analytics:not(#promo)`
2. Convert the NodeList to an Array
3. Filter the array using the predicate: `element => element.querySelector('your-selector')`

> #### `element.querySelector('your-selector')` will evaluate to `null` (which is falsey) if no child element is found

## Generally as a function

```js
function has(nodeList, selector) {
  return Array.from(nodeList).filter(e => e.querySelector(selector))
}

const nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('.main-container > .analytics:not(#promo)')

has(nodeList, 'a').forEach(e => e.style.background = "red")
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="analytics">
    <a>Should be red</a>
  </div>
  <div class="analytics">
    Should not be red
  </div>
  <div id="promo" class="analytics">
    <a>Should not be red</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

## As a NodeList.prototype

```js
NodeList.prototype.has = function(selector) {
  return Array.from(this).filter(e => e.querySelector(selector))
}

document
  .querySelectorAll('.main-container > .analytics:not(#promo)')
  .has('a')
  .forEach(e => e.style.background = 'red')
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="analytics">
    <a>Should be red</a>
  </div>
  <div class="analytics">
    Should not be red
  </div>
  <div id="promo" class="analytics">
    <a>Should not be red</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It returns `null` if there are no elements matching the selector, which when used in a truthy sense is false, but is not quite the same thing, and using `if(element.querySelector('your-selector') !== false)` would always be true.

Comment: Could you explain please why it doesn't properly work for elements which contains visited/unvisited links? https://jsfiddle.net/1bqdjfrg/

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Thanks. I thought it was a part of *"pseudo classes doesn't work with jQuery, but they works with plain JS"* case. But according to your comment, I was wrong. (?)

Answer (score 3):

You could select the `<a>` and then get their parentNodes:

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('.main-container .analytics:not(#promo) a');
var yourElements = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  yourElements.push(a[i].parentNode);
}

yourElements.forEach(e => e.style.background = "red");
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="analytics">
    <a>Should be red</a>
  </div>
  <div class="analytics">
    Should not be red
  </div>
  <div id="promo" class="analytics">
    <a>Schould not be red</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:** just noticed this only works if the `<a>` is a direct child of your wanted element.

Answer (score 3):

There is no equivalent selector for `:has`, you'll have to use an initial selection and then filter them

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.main-container > .analytics:not(#promo)');
var res = [];
for (let x = 0; x < el.length; x++){
    if (el[x].querySelector('a')) res.push(el[x]);
}
//res has has the array of elements needed.
```

Answer (score 0):

[Josh Larson's polyfill-css-has](https://github.com/jplhomer/polyfill-css-has) provides a `querySelectorAllWithHas` method based on vanilla JavaScript.