# How do I check if a div has something in it with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So my problem here is, I have these draggable elements that go from left div to right div and I need to count how many there are in the right divs, cause a function needs to be activated when all of them have something in it, how do I do that?

I tried with a check variable that was gonna add itself whenever something was dropped in a right div, but it gives me an error on the if, I don't know how to check if the paragraph with class "st" is inside one of the div

```js
function dragStart(event) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("Text", event.target.id);
  }
  
  function allowDrop(event) {
    if (event.target.getAttribute("draggable") == "true")
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "none"; // dropping is not allowed
    else
    event.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "all"; // drop it like it's hot
    event.preventDefault();
  }
    function drop(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
      event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
      var check = 0;
      var right = document.getElementById("right");
      for (var stct = 0; stct < 6; stct++) {
        console.log(right.getElementsByClassName("droptarget")[stct].getElementsByClassName("st").value);
        if (right.getElementsByClassName("droptarget")[stct].querySelector("st")) {
          check++;
        }
      }
    }
```

```css
#left{
    width:50%;
    height:90% !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    float:left;
}
#right{
    width:50%;
    height:90% !important;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    float:right;
}
.st{
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    font-size:40px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.droptarget {
  width: 120px; 
  height: 75px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
```

```html
    <div id="left">
      <div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p class="st" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget">12</p>
      </div>
      <div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
        <p class="st" ondragstart="dragStart(event)" draggable="true" id="dragtarget2">15</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      Forza :
      <div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      </div>
      Costituzione :
      <div class="droptarget" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update to a [mcve]

Comment: [Perhaps this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393309/is-there-a-vanilla-js-equivalent-of-jquery-has)

Comment: IIRC  querySelector() is always going to return a collection - you need to check its length to see if it actually contains anything.

Comment: I edited the snipped as asked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably check it with `Element.innerHTML`:

```js
const isEmptyEl = el => {
    return el.innerHTML.trim().length === 0;
}

console.log(isEmptyEl(document.querySelector(".filled"))); // false
console.log(isEmptyEl(document.querySelector(".empty"))); // true
```

```html
<div class="filled">
  <p></p>
</div>

<div class="empty">

</div>
```

Then you could do something like:

```js
const allElements = document.querySelectorAll(".droptarget");

if (Array.from(allElements).every(x => !isEmptyEl(x))) {
    // All elements have something dropped into them.
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked for me, didn't knew you could do something like that

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
if($('#right .droptarget').find('.st').length > 0)
```

if you want to check if in id=right with a child div with class=droptarget has a child with class=st

Comment: It does work but I need it to check only elements in the div with id="right"

Comment: The question does not mention that they are using jQuery, or willing to use it...

Comment: @Neyco i edited my answer. Did i understand you right?

Comment: jQuery is not a problem, I have it in my project already, sorry if I didn't mention it, but anyway, the .find("#right") would work if the right div was inside "droptarget" but it's his parent, I tried also $(this).parents().hasClass("right") but it doesn't work

Comment: sry i edited it again. maybe you can tell me the exact structure, so i can help you

Comment: Thank you, it worked but the other answer worked best for my problem, thanks a lot anyway!